# How to replace a missing value of a table with a cell in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, missing-data, cell-array

I'm using command 'readtable' to import data from excel files. All the data read in are strings and matlab uses NaN to represent missing values.

Is there a way to assign a cell to a missing value? Because I want to do a table to array conversion, and the existing of NaN keeps giving me error like "Cannot concatenate the table variables 'Var40' and 'Var39', because their types are double and cell".

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the code you used to produce that table. It looks to me like you inserted cells into the table. Like the error message shows, the types are char (a string) and cell. When creating the table, check the types of your inputs, they should be doubles if you want to get an array out of the table. As for the NA, that does not look like Matlab's representation of NaN, as it shouldn't be of type char.

Answer (score 0):

```
%These need to be the correct type! They cannot be cells or strings. If you 
%need to convert, do so before by extracting the contents of the variables, 
%like so: 
%var39 = var39{1}; 
%var40 = str2double(var40);
%var41 = var41{1};

var39 = 56.3584;
var40 = NaN;
var41 = 71.4144;

tbl = Table(var30, var40, var41);

ans = table2array(tbl);
```